# Как использовать virtual/override функции в C#?

Tags: c#, консоль, virtual, override, void

Я решил попробовать воспользоваться виртуальными функциями. У меня выводится только то, что было написано в виртуальной функции `Run()` в обобщающем классе `Animal`.

Вывод:
[image: Вывод:]
Вот код:
Обобщающий класс `Animal`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleAppTester
{
    public class Animal
    {
        protected virtual void Run()
        {
            Console.Write("Hello World! My name is");
        }

        public void Runsya()
        {
            Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Наследник `Dog`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleAppTester
{
    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        protected override void Run()
        {
            base.Run();
            Console.WriteLine("Dog!");
        }
    }
}
```

Наследник `Cat`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleAppTester
{
    public class Cat : Animal
    {
        protected override void Run()
        {
            base.Run();
            Console.WriteLine("Cat!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну видимо потому что ты создаёшь экземпляр класса Animal, а не производных

Comment: Больше ничего не могу сказать без вызывающего кода

Comment: Ошибка за пределами показанного кода.

Comment: Ваш вопрос низкого качества. Ознакомьтесь с информацией из справки [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и написали в комментах ошибка за пределами показанного кода. Единственное, что могу подсказать - попробуй собрать такой пример:

```
public class Animal
{
  protected virtual void Run()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World! My name is");
  }

  public void Runsya()
  {
    this.Run();
  }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
  protected override void Run()
  {
    base.Run();
    Console.WriteLine("Dog");
  }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
  protected override void Run()
  {
    base.Run();
    Console.WriteLine("Cat");
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Animal dog = new Dog();
  dog.Runsya();
  Animal cat = new Cat();
  cat.Runsya();
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```